# CSS won't link to my page.php template in Wordpress, everything else works fine

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

So I am going through a Wordpress theme course, and we are creating our page template setup. The page is loading fine with

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="page-template">
  <div class="container">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

All my css files are linked into the header, but for some reason when I load up the pages I create, they don't load up the CSS we created for the page. We are importing all the css files into one main.css file, this is the one I am having trouble with.

```
@import "pagetemplate/page.css";
```

and in that file we have some basic css to test it out and make sure it connects.

```
#page-template {padding: 80px 0;}
#page-template .container {padding: 0 15px;}
```

Sorry if it's all over the place, I will be glad to expand on any questions.

I should add, my header.php page has the css link of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/main.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the php code to

```
<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>
```

So you link look like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I'm a bit confused by your answer : `<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>` in your top codeblock does not match the same element in the next codeblock : `<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` Please can you give a more detailed explanation and / or correct the code _ thanks : )

Comment: Sorry! I appreciate the answer but I am not sure what I am changing? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Thanks and really sorry for my mistake. I update the code. Can you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that didn't work for me. My css is working fine on my main theme, but I am setting up my page.php template for when I create extra pages and the ```<?php get_header(); ?>``` is not finding the link css even though it is there. Anyways, I posted an answer below that worked for me. I just linked the css file I needed into my page.php template.

Comment: Can you please share your <head> css links for a view?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just figured it out. I am not sure if it's good practice the way I did it but I got it! I just linked the css folder and file straight into the page.php.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/page-template/mypage.css">
```

I added this regular css link into my page.php template, since my get_header() is not recognizing my css link from my main page.
Here is the final view.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/page-template/mypage.css">
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="page-temp">
  <div class="container">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```